# Best practice: Handle first/last item in foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Many times I ran into a situation like this

```
$str = '';
foreach($arr as $item)
{
    $str .= $item . ',';
}
```

The result would be something like `$str = item1,item2,item3,`. But I dont want the `,` at the end.

Now there are some ways to get rid of the `,`.
E.g.

- use `substr()` to cut of the `,`.
- write a function to detect the last item and alter the body of the loop to

  ```
  $str .= $item;  
  if(!last($item)) 
     $str .= ',';
  ```

  I think this is good readable, but the programm checks every item if it is the last one, which is obviously only one time the case.
- use `implode(',', $arr)` (*But lets assume that this is not possible. Think about a more complex body of the loop*)

**What would be best practice to handle the last (or the first) item in a foreach loop?**

Comment: There is no single answer for this. It will depend entirely on what your loop is doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In languages that do not have a `join`-like method, this is what I've used (and seen used) for a while.

```
result = ""
delim = ""
foreach(string in array)
   result += delim + string
   delim = ","
```

<sup>(Apply to your favorite language)</sup>

In your case using PHP, it would look like

```
$str = "";
$delim = "";
foreach($arr as $item) {
    $str .= $delim + $item;
    $delim = ",";
}
```

Comment: This is realy nice :)

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this Example it may solve your hurdle.**

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$copy = $arr;
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    echo $val;
    if (next($copy )) {
        echo ','; // Add comma for all elements instead of last
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `rtrim` to remove last unwanted character(s)

```
$str = rtrim($str, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

This might also be a way:

```
$last = end($arr);   // returns the last item and sets the internal pointer to the end
unset($arr[key($arr)])   // deletes the last item from the array
$str = '';
foreach($arr as $item)
{
    $str .= $item . ',';
}
$str .= $last;
```

This does not check or assign anything additional in the loop, but I think it is not a good readable way.